# Find To My Button Field Name Via Reflection Or Other Way

Tags: java, android

I have two classes - my main Android activity class, and my reflection class. I am using Android Studio.

In my main activity class I have one button. I want to make it so that when I press this button I should get the name of the button which is defined in strings.xml.

**I don't want to use getText() so don't tell me to use it.** I want to use reflection or any other good way.

In my reflection class I used reflection to get my field which I defined in my main activity class and put it into a string variable. When I show this value using a toast it's giving me a **null** value.

**My Reflection Class**

```
public class Reflection extends MyActivity

    static public String Value;
    public static void Cool() {
        MyActivity myActivity=new MyActivity(); // Creating Android Main Activity Class Object
        try {
            Field field=myActivity.getClass().getField("btnFIRST"); //btnFirst Field Which i Defined In Android Main Activity Class
            field.setAccessible(true);
            Value=(String)field.get(myActivity);
        }
        catch (Exception E){
            E.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Android Main Activity Class**

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    Reflection ref; // Here I Am Creating My Reflection Class Object

    Button btnFIRST;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
        btnFIRST = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnFIRST);
        ref=new Reflection(); // Reflection Class New Object

        ref.Cool(); // Here I Am Calling My Cool Method Which Define In My Reflection Class

        btnFIRST.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "Found Button Name="+ref.Value, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
            }
        });
    }
}
```

See here: `+ref.Value` I want to print my button value name, which is "(Click)" defined in strings.xml. But I am getting a null value instead.

I should be getting the output "Found Button Name=Click".

Comment: Do you know what a class is?

Comment: what a class mean........

Answer (score 0):

When you construct an instance of `MainActivity`, the value of `btnFIRST` for the instance is `null`. This is because `btnFIRST` is assigned only in the `onCreate()` method, which is never called on that instance.

You might think all you have to do is call `onCreate()` before trying to access the field, but that won't work either: you will get an exception. This is because the instance of `MainActivity` has not been properly set up (e.g., it doesn't have a proper `Context`, it does not have a `Widnow`, etc), so it won't be able to inflate the layout. The Android OS is responsible for doing this setup; it's not something you can do yourself. In general it is **ALWAYS** a bad idea to construct Activities yourself via their constructor.

That said, I can find absolutely no reason at all you would need to use reflection to obtain the text of this button. Unless you can give us a compelling reason why this would be necessary, **you should just use `getText()`.**

Alternatively, if you know the string resource ID, you can call `getString(...)` in your Activity.

Comment: K Thanks Karakuri But No Other Way To Get Views name Suppose I Am Using Voice Enabling App And In My App 20 Views There(like text box,button,edit box bala bala) And I Wana Get All Views By Name then Its Easy To Put 100   Views  just call by name....how same gettext() method

Comment: Without knowing what you are actually trying to do, I can't offer you much advice. Maybe try traversing the view hierarchy and calling `getText()` on anything that is an instance of `TextView` (which will include subclasses like `Button`).